# Why "require" cannot find a file in Ruby on Rails 3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, require

I would to populate the database (MySQL) with some dummy entries as the application starts.

I created:

```
class DatabaseInitializer
  def populate_database
    ...
  end
end
```

in `lib/database_initializer.rb`.

I understand that all files in the `lib` directory should have been loaded automatically.

**Question 1:** Is there any command to see a list of all files that have been loaded ?

Then, in `controllers/main_controller.rb` I have:

```
require 'lib/database_initializer.rb'
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def initialize
    DatabaseInitializer.new.populate_database
  end
  def index
    ...
  end  
end
```

But, I got the following error:

```
LoadError in MainController#index
no such file to load -- lib/database_initializer.rb
```

**Question 2:** Why it cannot find `database_initializer.rb` ?

**Question 3:** Is this "Rails enough" way to pre-populate a database ? Would you do this otherwise (put `database_initializer.rb` in other place, call `DatabaseInitializer.new.populate_database` from other place, e.t.c.) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1**

```
$LOADED_FEATURES
```

**Question 2**

```
# the 'lib' directory is already added to the load
# path in the Rails initialization process, so simply:
require 'database_initializer`
```

**Question 3**

```
# db/seeds.rb
c = Company.create! :name => 'ABC Inc.'
p = Person.create! :name => 'Jeremy', :company => c

$ rake db:seed
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helps. One more question: what is the difference between `create!` and `create` in your code ?

Comment: create! throws an exception if it fails whereas create just returns false. It's a common pattern in ActiveRecord however generally in ruby a bang_method! indicates that the method alters the receiver directly rather than returning a new object. See Array#reverse and Array#reverse!

Comment: Thanks! Is it always recommended to use `create!` rather than `create` when creating records in database (I do want to know if something goes wrong) ?

Answer (score 2):

When requiring files from ruby you generally drop the file extension. Try `require database_initializer`. `lib/` was briefly removed from the load path in rails-3 but I think it's back now. If not, see `config.autoload_paths` in `config/application.rb`.

However, I think this is probably a bad idea in general. If you need to ensure that you always have a consistent and immutable set of data available to your app, why not just define it in ruby in a model?

Also, there is already a mechanism for adding seed data in rails. See `db/seeds.rb` and the command `rake db:seed`

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely use `db/seeds.rb` from now!

Answer (score 1):

For any file in lib, you should only have to use: `require 'database_initializer'`.